# android application doing force close

Tags: android, image-processing, forceclose

I am new to android. I am trying to do some kind of image processing. But I am getting this message "This application --- has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.". Kindly tell me what mistake I am making

```
package com.imagep.amit;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImagepActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Bitmap myBitmap;
    ImageView myImageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String imageFileName= "/sdcard/test_vga.jpg";
        File imageFile= new File(imageFileName);
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            // Load the image from file
            myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileName);
            // Display the image in the image viewer
            myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.di);
            if (myImageView!= null) {
                myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
        this.processImage();
    }

    private void processImage() {
        brighten(50);
        try {
            String outputPath= "/test_vga_output.jpg";
            int quality = 75;
            FileOutputStream fileOutStr= new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
            BufferedOutputStream bufOutStr= new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutStr);
            myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bufOutStr);
            bufOutStr.flush();
            bufOutStr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            Log.e("debug_log", exception.toString());
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e("debug_log", exception.toString());
        }
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

    private void brighten(int i) {
        int width = myBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = myBitmap.getHeight();
        int[] pix = new int[width * height];
        myBitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        // Apply pixel-by-pixel change
        int index = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int r = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b = pix[index] & 0xff;
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
                pix[index++] = 0xff000000| (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            } // x 
        } // y
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, You need to post the LogCat logs too, to know which Exception you are getting and at which line. If you are using eclipse, it'll be at lower bottom. Just copy and paste here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.

In addition, **never hardwire paths**, particularly since `/sdcard` is wrong -- use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of external storage.

Finally, your actual problem probably comes from:

```
String outputPath= "/test_vga_output.jpg";
```

which is an invalid path. I do not know where you think you are writing, but you cannot write there. However,  you may have additional problems beyond that, and the stack trace will help you identify them.